# SASS / SCSS use variable to define several properties?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I want to do the following:

```
$test: color: red; background-color: green; font-size: $foo;
```

is there a way, if not, what am I supposed to do instead?

[codepen is spitting an error at me](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLqvmY) when trying to do the above mentioned.

Comment: This is what mixins are for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define multiple properties in Sass you can use a map, as follows:

```
$test: (
    item-one: red, 
    item-two: green, 
    item-three: $foo
);
```

However, you can't achieve what you're attempting to achieve with a map as properties are only allowed *within* rules.

As pointed out by [cimmanon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652962/cimmanon), you're better off using a mixin.

Comment: what is the typical use case for a map?

Comment: Project configuration alongside keeping your Sass DRY seem to be the biggest use cases. There's a great article over at [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/) which gives a little more information on using Sass for Project Configs, Module Configs, Creating DRY Sass and CSS Dumping. Definitely worth a read! I've also put a quick [Gist](http://sassmeister.com/gist/2f29582169fb2d18b815) up on [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/) to give you a real-world example.

Comment: hm no i don't understand how I am supposed to use the map. I am only able to use it within a rule? what? well all I do with variable definitions is finally use it in a css rule. E.g. can you show a snippet where you use a map?